# Live Visual Tree for Win32 apps

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

I have worked on XAML-based UWP apps and the [Live Visual Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/inspect-xaml-properties-while-debugging?view=vs-2022#look-at-elements-in-the-live-visual-tree) feature proved handy sometimes to inspect the actual dimensions and properties of UI elements within the app. Is there something similar to inspect native elements within a **Win32 desktop app** where I can query the dimensions of native views within the app?

Comment: Windows SDK used to include a tool named Spy++, and there are plenty of clones around.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4537611/103167) for a screenshot, showing that it displays the dimensions of child windows.

Comment: I would suggest a UIA inspection tool instead of spy++. UIA can tell you the size and location of things that aren't HWND-based.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Using [Accesiibilty Insights](https://accessibilityinsights.io/downloads/) did the trick for me.

Comment: "Acc" makes me think it's based on the older active accessibility API. While that should be sufficient for size and location, UIA can tell you a whole lot more.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Would you suggest using the `VisualUIAVerifyNative` that's bundled with the SDK? That doesn't seem to highlight the exact element that I'm interested in though it does highlight other elements. I'm not sure why that's the case.

Comment: Ok, I used the [Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) UIA tool which seems to offer much more information (regarding `hWnd` wherever applicable)

Comment: I do like Visual UIA Verify (and note I depend heavily upon accessibility as I am blind). I am surprised there would be anything that shows up in an active accessibility tool that doesn't in UIA (though not by the reverse).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're *specifically* asking for native windows, recursively calling [`EnumChildWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows) is the appropriate solution. Once you have an `HWND` you can call [`GetWindowRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect) to retrieve the window dimensions.